# clearcase: how to check if code from stream A has been delivered to stream B

Tags: clearcase

How can I check if the code in a stream A has been delivered to stream B using the command line. Internally we are using Clearcase UCM.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check the difference between stream A and stream B, using [**`cleartool diffbl`**](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_diffbl.htm):

```
cleartool diffbl -act stream:Stream1@\aPVob stream:StreamB@\aPVob
```

What you are looking for are unlabelled baselined (technical baselines set by ClearCase), created from **activities** (hence the `-act`) named `deliver.xxx`:

```
Differences:
<< deliver.java_dev.19990917.140443 "deliver java_dev on 09/17/99 14:04:43."
<< deliver.java_dev.19990917.141046 "deliver java_dev on 09/17/99 14:10:46."
```

If you describes those activities, you will know what *versions* have been delivered.

```
cleartool descr activity:deliver.java_dev.19990917.140443@\aPVob
```

The issue is: once delivered, what you get in `streamB` is one giant activity (the "`deliver.xxx`" one) with all the delivered *versions* in it.
You don't have directly the list of contributing activities which were on `StreamA`, and were part of the deliver.

To see those contributing activities, you can look at the technote "[Activities delivered since the last baseline](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21136012)":

> The above output will display the **integration activities associated with the deliver operations** to that stream.
>   If you would like to obtain a list of contributing activities for the associated integration activities, the following command can be issued for each integration activity respectively:
>
> Example:

```
%> cleartool lsact -contrib activity:deliver.development_steam.20010824.080503@/vobstore/pvob

ACT0000435
```

Comment: What's the '@\aPvob' stuff mean?

Comment: @sashang it is an example. Please adapt the stream name and pvob name to your case. If you are on unix, that can be `@/vobs/yourPVob`

Comment: I tried but got an error: ct diffbl -bas stream:coremw3.1_dev@/vobs/coremw/pvob stream:coremw3.1_dev_opensaf@/vobs/coremw/pvob
cleartool: Error: The -baseline option cannot be used with a stream.

Comment: @sashang true, try with `-act`